# Run JNLP files from terminal without third party plugins on MAC

Tags: java, terminal, jnlp

I can double click on my application from the Finder window but I am not able to figure out what is the same command from the terminal so that I can create a Alias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `javaws` ("Java Web Start")

plus the pathname or URL of the jnlp. See also `javaws --help`

Comment: Thanks, I read about javaws but for some reason I thought I could leverage what is already builtin into Finder. Is that not possible?

Comment: I don't know why I didn't try to run javaws before considering installation but either comes built in with the mac or when I installed JAVA it was installed and it is available. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help. javaws it's part of oracle java .